# permission error on modifying root owned authorized keys file

Tags: bash, shell

i need to exchange public key between two systems A and B.

These are the steps am following

1. copy the content of id_rsa.pub from /root/.ssh directory  and save it in variable 'key'
2. ssh to B as ubuntu user . ssh -i key_file ubuntu@B
3. Move to root login by sudo su
4. Append the variable $key to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

But the file authorized_keys is owned by root. Hence i get the permission error.

I cannot directory connect to system B as root. Only way is to connect as ubuntu and change to root.

I tried the following shell script

```
# Get all the Ips from the source file
sudo grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $1 | sort -u > /tmp/list_of_servers.txt

# Get the public key 
pubkey=$(sudo cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)

# For each server
while read ip;
do
    (echo "$ip"
    # ssh to the server
    ssh -i $2 $3@$ip
    # append key to autorized_keys file
    sudo -c "echo $pubkey >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys" root
    echo "done $ip" )

done < /tmp/list_of_servers.txt
```

but i didnt work. its giving me permission error.

Can someone help me in the last step.

Comment: That `sudo` command in the loop isn't happening on the remote server. It is happening locally.

Comment: can you pls help with the syntax to do it on remote server ?

Comment: Send the command to ssh. Look up how to do it it's been asked many times

Comment: In a script `ssh` doesn't start an interactive session and take over reading input (the way it does when you run it manually). Look all over this site and the internet for how to give `ssh` a command to run remotely.

Comment: Also `sudo -c` is not valid. Perhaps you mean to use `su`?

Comment: Above and beyond the other problems, lots of quoting issues here, too. http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend, though it won't find quite all of them.

Comment: Perhaps something more like `ssh -i key_file ubuntu@B sudo su root -c 'dd of=/root/.ssh/authorized_keys oflag=append' < /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` would work out better. You might possibly need to use nested quotes on the `dd` bit - i.e. `... '"dd ..."' ...` - I don't have a system handy to test that on at the moment...

Comment: @twalberg, doing the shell quoting yourself -- `ssh ... "sudo su root -c 'dd ...'"` -- would avoid the issue. (As given, I expect the code in your comment not to work, since ssh doesn't pass the literal argv array through).

Answer (score 1):

A fully paranoid approach to the mechanics of the SSH connection might be something like this:

```
# generate a shell-escaped version of the public key (spaces, wildcards, etc)
printf -v pubkey_q '%q' "$pubkey"

# generate a shell command using that quoted form
cmd="echo $pubkey_q >>/root/.ssh/authorized_keys"

# generate a shell-quoted sudo command invoking the above in a shell
printf -v cmd_q '%q ' sudo bash -c "$cmd"

# ...and execute it on the other end of a ssh connection.
ssh -i "$2" "$3@$ip" "$cmd_q"
```

`printf %q` is a bash extension which escapes a string in such a way that being parsed by a shell -- whether in a string that's `eval`'d, passed to `ssh` with bash as the remote shell, or passed to `bash -c` -- evaluates back to the original data. (For regular whitespace its output is safe for `sh -c` as well, but for any content where bash prefers `$''` to escape nonprintable characters, this output may not be POSIX compliant).

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
# ssh to the server
ssh -i $2 $3@$ip
# append key to autorized_keys file
sudo -c "echo $pubkey >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys" root
```

The ssh command there would normally open an interactive remote shell, but since we are in a script, an interactive shell is not possible. So the remote shell immediately exits, without actually doing anything at all.

The sudo command that follows is incorrect syntax, it cannot work that way with the `-c` flag. Check the man page of `sudo`. And since you are not actually in the remote she'll as you may have believed, the command is running in your local system, not the remote one where you want to append your key.

To run sudo remotely, use something like this:

```
ssh -i $2 $3@$ip sudo echo hello
```

The echo is just an example for testing of course.

However, this whole attempt of appending a public key to the authorized list of root is deeply flawed in terms of security. Sudo should be configured to ask for the password of the user, and there is no good way to do that in a script. Or if the user can run sudo without entering a password, that's just unacceptable from a security perspective.

Comment: Better practice would be `ssh -i "$2" "$3@$ip" "sudo echo hello"`. (If `ssh` receives multiple arguments for the command portion, it just concatenates them with spaces into a single string for remote evaluation with `sh -c`; better to do that yourself and thus have more control).